# Match only the attribute of the defined tag

Tags: regex

I have defined my own tags and attributes, like `[TITLE|prefix=X]`. Now I would like to get the value of the attribute `prefix`, which is defined for the tag `[TITLE]`.

This is what I have used:

```
(?<=TITLE[^\]].+prefix=)[^\]|]+
```

If the string is `[TITLE][DYNAMIC|prefix=Y]`, it works fine, since there is no match but if the string is `[TITLE|suffix=X][DYNAMIC|prefix=Y]`, it gives me the wrong value but it should be no match too.

See https://regexr.com/5gmmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the tag boundaries with square brackets. So, use them inside a negated character class:

```js
(?<=TITLE[^\][]*\|prefix=)[^\]|]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HiLH8w/2). A capturing pattern would be

```js
TITLE[^\][]*\|prefix=([^\]|]+)
```

Here,

- `(?<=TITLE[^\][]*\|prefix=)`  -  a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `TITLE` - literal string
  - `[^\][]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `\|prefix=` - a `|prefix=` string
- `[^\]|]+` - one or more chars other than `]` and `|`. In JavaScript regex flavor, the `]` inside a character class in the initial position must be escaped.

Comment: That is just too perfect! Thank you!